# How to find the Lagrangian of this system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, differential-equations, variational-calculus

I am trying to find the Lagrangian $L$ of a system I am studying. The equations of motion is:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     r \ddot{\phi} + 2\dot{r} \dot{\phi}+k(r) \cdot r \dot{r} \dot{\phi} = 0\\
     \ddot{r} - r \dot{\phi}^2 - k(r) \cdot r^2 \dot{\phi}^2 = 0
\end{array}\right.$$

I have tried a general Ansatz $L=L_1+L_2=\Sigma_{m,n,p,q} C_{m,n,p,q} r^m \dot{r}^n \phi^p 
 \dot{\phi}^q+L_2(k(r))$ and plugged into the Euler-Lagrange equation but find the calculation extremely tedious. Is there some systematic way to find it?

I'd really appreciate any hints. Thank you!

---

Update:

By a little bit rearrangement,
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     \ddot{\phi} + F(r) \dot{r} \dot{\phi}= 0\\
     \ddot{r} +G(r) \dot{\phi}^2 = 0
\end{array}\right.$$
where
\begin{equation}
F(r)=\frac{2}{r} + k(r), \quad G(r)=-(r+k(r)\cdot r^2)
\end{equation}

If we assume
$$L=A(r) \dot{r}^2 + B(r) \dot{\phi}^2 +C(r) \dot{r} \dot{\phi}$$
(so that I can get the metric easily)

Then
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     \mathscr{L}_r L = 2A \ddot{r} -B_r \dot{\phi}^2+C\ddot{\phi} +A_r \dot{r}^2\\
     \mathscr{L}_\phi L = 2B \ddot{\phi} +2B_r \dot{r}\dot{\phi}+C_r\dot{r}^2 + C \ddot{r}
\end{array}\right.$$
where $\mathscr{L}_q L \equiv \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\right)-\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{q}}$

By comparison with the EOM, it requires
$$\frac{2A}{1}= \frac{-B_r}{G(r)}, \quad \frac{2B}{1}=\frac{2B_r}{F(r)}, \quad C=0, \quad A_r=0$$

It seems fine except for $A_r=0$ is conflicting with the others.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you get the  EOMs in the first place?

Comment: @Qmechanic, actually they are just $a_{\phi} + k(r) v_r v_{\phi} =0$ and $a_r  -k(r) v_{\phi}^2 = 0$.

Comment: Could these be the geodesic equations of some rotationally invariant Riemannisn metric? Rotationally invariant, because they have a one parameter group of symmetries $\phi \to \phi + s$. This coefficient $k(r)$ could be a Christoffel symbol?

Comment: @Futurologist, I have tried a little bit with the rotational invariance. However it seems some conflicts exist. I have updated the work in the description. I really appreciate your attention.

Comment: @ShengkaiLi It's nice you have worked out the equations. Maybe try to not set $C=0$ and then simply apply the inverse matrix of the matrix formed by $A, B, C$ to the equations. You gonna get more complicated coefficients with unknown functions $A, B, C$. Maybe this could work but of course there is no guarantee unless you try it.

Comment: From a comment of OP it seems that we have the motion of a point particle under the influence of a force :
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}  = m\mathbf{a}=m \left(a_r\mathbf{e}_{r}+a_\phi\mathbf{e}_{\phi}\right)= m k(r) \upsilon_{\phi}\left(\upsilon_{\phi}\mathbf{e}_{r}-\upsilon_r\mathbf{e}_{\phi}\right)
\tag{com-01}
\end{equation}
always normal to its velocity :
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\left(t\right)=\dot{r}\mathbf{e}_{r}+ r\dot{\phi}\,\mathbf{e}_{\phi}=\upsilon_r\mathbf{e}_{r}+\upsilon_{\phi}\,\mathbf{e}_{\phi}
\tag{com-02}
\end{equation}
as the magnetic force for example.

Comment: @Frobenius Yes, this system conserves the speed. Good catch. Additionally, the azimuthal acceleration vanishes when exactly going inwards or outwards ($v_\phi = 0$). Does that mean I have to have an external force part on the right hand side of the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: @Futurologist About the matrix you mentioned, do you mean the matrix $M$ in $L=(\dot{r} \quad  \dot{\phi}) M (\dot{r} \quad \dot{\phi})^T$?

Comment: @Frobenius Or construct a vector potential field like for the charged particle in a magnetic field?

Comment: @Shengkai Li  I apologize, but I'll continue tomorrow. Note that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathbf{F}}{m}=\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}  \quad\text{where} \quad \mathbf{B}=k(r)\upsilon_{\phi}\mathbf{e}_{z} 
\tag{com-03}
\end{equation}

Comment: Not to distract you, but have you noticed $\phi$  is absent, so you might as well define $\theta\equiv\dot{\phi}$ and the equation for it is 1st, not second order.  But a Lagrangian for it may be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find the metric for these equations:
\begin{align*}
  &\ddot{\varphi} +F(r)\,\dot{\varphi}\,\dot{r}=0&(1) \\
  &\ddot{r}  +G(r)\,\left(\dot{\varphi}\right)^2=0&(2)
\end{align*}
$\textbf{Theory}$

The equations of motions are: (I use the NEWTON EULER method )
\begin{align*}
  &J^T J \,\ddot{\vec{q}}  =- J^T\,\frac{\partial\left( J\,\dot{\vec{q}}\right)}{\partial\vec{q}}\,\dot{\vec{q}}+J^T\,\vec{f_a}&(3)\\
\end{align*}
With vector $\vec{q}$ of the generalized coordinates:
\begin{align*}
\vec{q}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \varphi \\
      r \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*},
the Jacobi-Matrix (Ansatz):
\begin{align*}
  J&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    r & 0 \\
    \varphi & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and the vector $\vec{f_a}$ of the external forces (Ansatz):
\begin{align*}
\vec{f_a}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     0 \\
      -\frac{\varphi}{r}\,\dot{\varphi}\,\dot{r} \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
We get the equation of motions (with (3)):
\begin{align*}
  &\ddot{\varphi} +\frac{1}{r}\,\dot{\varphi}\,\dot{r}=0& (4)\\
  &\ddot{r}  +\left(\dot{\varphi}\right)^2=0&(5)
\end{align*}
Compare the coefficients of equation (1) with (4) and (2) with (5) we get:
\begin{align*}
  F(r) & =\frac{2}{r}+k_1(r)\overset{!}{=}\frac{1}{r} \,\Rightarrow\quad
  k_1(r)=-\frac{1}{r}\\
  G(r) &=-\left(r+k_2(r)\,r^2\right)\overset{!}{=}1\,\Rightarrow\quad
  k_2(r)=-{\frac {r+1}{{r}^{2}}}
\end{align*}
To fulfill the equations (1) and (2)   I have to take two functions $k_1(r)$ and $k_2(r)$.

$\textbf{Metric}:$

\begin{align*}
&g=J^T\,J=
\begin{bmatrix}
  r^2+\varphi^2 & \varphi \\
  \varphi & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting the $k(r)$'s are limited to make the ansatz work.